# Using datacamp light exercises in an ioslides presentation using the tutorial package

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, ioslides

The `tutorial` packages allows to include a `datacamp` interactive `R` window in an html document:

````
    ---
title: "Example Document"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: FALSE
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
tutorial::go_interactive()
```

By default, `tutorial` will convert all R chunks.

```{r}
a <- 2
b <- 3

a + b
```
````

I therefore thought it might be able to use it within an HTML5 presentation, for example like this:

````
---
title: "Example Document"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    self_contained: FALSE
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
tutorial::go_interactive()
```

By default, `tutorial` will convert all R chunks.

```{r}
a <- 2
b <- 3

a + b
```
````

However, that only created nonsense.
Has anyone experience in getting this to work?

P.S.: The best result so far is a long alphanumeric string instead of a console in browser window (Google Chrome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the converting process, the HTML generated by the `tutorial` package gets encoded. An easy solution is to wrap your chunks like this:

````
<!--html_preserve-->
```{r}
a <- 2
b <- 3

a + b
```
<!--/html_preserve-->
````

leading to the HTML code generated being untouched.

[image]

To fix the glitches resulting from CSS conflicts you can add the following CSS right at the beginning of your document:

```
    <style>
/* Rearrange console label */
.datacamp-exercise ol li, .datacamp-exercise ul li {
  margin-bottom: 0em !important;
}

/* Remove bullet marker */
.datacamp-exercise ol li::before, .datacamp-exercise ul li::before {
  content: '' !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool, thanks. A shame that the Console tab seems to be hanging off centre.

Comment: I am so sorry. I didn not recognize that glitch. I added a way to fix this.

Comment: Brilliant, this is really great. I'll torture my students with this next term (evil laugh)...

Comment: Very handy is also to use `tutorial::go_interactive(greedy=FALSE)` and only use interactive chunks with `tut=TRUE` in the Chunk options!

Comment: This now messes up ordered lists, but it's fine if you can use bullet points instead.

Comment: Fixed it. Now the CSS only applies to lists inside elements of class `.datacamp-exercise`. Sorry, I do not always have a complete presentation to make sure everything works.